# c# wpf Exception Unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a problem with wpf and changing two wpf pages while pressing button. when i press the button that should go to the other page, visual-studio throws this error:

`System.InvalidOperationException`: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Boozes' of type 'DatabaseBoozeWpf.ViewModels.MainWindowVM'.'

my code for button:

```
private void exitAddItemWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow sK = new MainWindow();
    sK.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

If i try same project in other computer, it works. What should I do?

My Xaml code: exit button will activate exitAddItemWindow

```
<Window x:Class="DatabaseBoozeWpf.AddItemsForm.AddItemWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatabaseBoozeWpf.AddItemsForm"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Add items" Height="300" Width="400">
<Grid Background="#e6e6e6">
    <Button Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,179,0,0" Background="#FF3496B4" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="exitAddItemWindow" Width="60" Height="19">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,179,0,0" Background="#FF3496B4" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="loginNewWindow" Width="75" Height="19">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="229,55,0,0" Background="#FF79DCFA"
             BorderBrush="#FF0040FF" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">

    </TextBox>
    <PasswordBox Name="TextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Background="#FF79DCFA" BorderBrush="#FF0040FF"
             Margin="229,101,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <PasswordBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="25"/>
        </Style>
    </PasswordBox.Resources>
    </PasswordBox>
    <Label Content="Username:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Label Content="Password:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Code For `MainWindow.Xaml`:

```
<Window x:Name="Bar" x:Class="DatabaseBoozeWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatabaseBoozeWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Virtual Bar" Height="450" Width="625">
<Grid Background="#e6e6e6">

    <ListBox Name="BoozeList" Margin="10,124,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Width="233" Background="#FF79DCFA" BorderBrush="#FF0040FF">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat={}{0} Euros }" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity, StringFormat={}{0} ml }" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BoozesCollection" Source="{Binding Boozes}"/>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="JuicesCollection" Source="{Binding Juices}"/>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SnacksCollection" Source="{Binding Snacks}"/>

            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource BoozesCollection}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource JuicesCollection}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource SnacksCollection}}"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,92,0,0"
    Name="SearchBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"
    Background="#FF51C1FA"
             Text="{Binding Boozes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Resources>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    <Button Content="Add to cart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FF3496B4">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button >

    <PasswordBox Name="Pass" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,0,0,114" Width="82" Background="#FF51C1FA" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <PasswordBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </PasswordBox.Resources>
    </PasswordBox>

    <Button Content="Pay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="498,0,0,113" Width="79" Background="#FF3496B4"
            Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click_2">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>

    <ListBox Name="OrderList"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,92,0,193" Width="166" Background="#FF79DCFA" BorderBrush="#FF0040FF" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>
    <Label Content="Cart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77"/>
    <Label Content="Enter your pincode:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,0,0,132" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Button Content="Remove from cart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="106" Height="22" Click="Button_Click_1" Background="#FF3496B4">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button >
    <Button Content="Add items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="502,0,0,26" Click="btnAddItems" 
            Width="75" Background="#FF3496B4" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

    <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="77" Click="Button_Click_3" Background="#FF3496B4" Height="24">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button >


</Grid>
```

`MainWindowVM.cs` code:

```
public class MainWindowVM : BaseVM
{
    private List<Booze> _boozes;



    public List<Booze> Boozes
    {
        get { return _boozes; }
        private set
        {
            _boozes = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Boozes");
        }
    }


    private IBoozeService _boozeService;

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _boozes = new List<Booze>();
        _boozeService = new BoozeService(new BoozeDbContext());
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        Boozes = _boozeService.GetAllBoozes();

    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your `XAML`.

Comment: Added XAML code

Comment: Could you show us XAML of `MainWindow`?

Comment: Added `MainWindow` code

Comment: And finally please post your `Boozes` property from `ViewModel`.

Comment: Added `ViewModel` code

Comment: In your `set` property `Boozes` remove `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Mode` of the binding to the `Booze` property to `OneWay` in your XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Booze, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

...or add a public setter to the `Booze` source property:

```
public string Booze { get; set; }
```